# Find num value in array keys

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

//I have array like that:

```
$roms = array (

[1] => 2
[2] => 4
[6] => 2
    [7] => 7

)
```

//I have data table like bellow:

```
ID               room             total_room

1                 1b/1b             7

2                 2b/2b             12

6                 3b/ 2b            32

8                 3b/3b             7
```

//when I query result

```
$total_rooms   = 0 ;

foreach( $query->result() as $row ) 
{

    if  ( $row->ID , array_keys($rooms) ) :
        $total_rooms[] = array_values( $rooms ); // from array values
    else:
        $total_rooms[] = $row->total_room;  // from table
    endif;

}
```

//I want result like that:

```
$total_rooms = 2; // array value
$total_rooms = 4; // array value
$total_rooms = 2; // array value
$total_rooms = 7; // not array value : becos no ID in keys
```

But this code not work for me!

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement and following line is a little weird, try this:

```
if(array_key_exists($row->ID, $rooms)) :
    $total_rooms[] = $rooms[$row->ID]; // from array
else:
    $total_rooms[] = $row->total_room;  // from table
endif;
```

**Note:** you are assigning a new **array** key to `$total_rooms` each time, are you sure you don't just want it to be a regular old variable? See:

```
$total_rooms = $rooms[$row->ID]; // from array
```

[`array_key_exists()` manual](http://php.net/array_key_exists)

Comment: It will return the result from the array if the array key exists, otherwise it will use the database table info.

Comment: How can I get number of $total_rooms instead array?

Comment: Not sure what you mean sorry, try the code above and see how it goes for you.

Comment: @SherAh no problem - I notice you haven't accepted any answers on your questions. Please visit http://stackoverflow.com/tour and read the section about how to accept answers on your questions - it benefits both you (you'll get a badge for your first accepted answer) and the answerer (who gets reputation for it)